# How to resolve this cmd.exe exception?

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-server-2012

I am trying to start a task from the task scheduler. The task will basically run a 'runas /savecred /user:abc job.bat' to start a process. However it has failed. I find this error message in event log and I think it can be relevant.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          3/10/2015 1:52:39 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      WIN-PLMLT7HVCLA
Description:
Faulting application name: cmd.exe, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108a15
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.17046, time stamp: 0x53b4864c
Exception code: 0xc0000142
Fault offset: 0x00000000000e2000
Faulting process id: 0x1114
Faulting application start time: 0x01d05ad4e3fc0903
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
Faulting module path: KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 21ad5685-c6c8-11e4-945e-062e57f301ba
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-03-10T01:52:39.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>14096</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>WIN-PLMLT7HVCLA</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>cmd.exe</Data>
    <Data>6.2.9200.16384</Data>
    <Data>50108a15</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.2.9200.17046</Data>
    <Data>53b4864c</Data>
    <Data>c0000142</Data>
    <Data>00000000000e2000</Data>
    <Data>1114</Data>
    <Data>01d05ad4e3fc0903</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>21ad5685-c6c8-11e4-945e-062e57f301ba</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

If I run `runas /savecred /user:abc job.bat` directly in a DOS prompt, it works without issue.

The reason I cannot run it as `abc` directly is because it use MS Office COM object. When it tries to open a powerpoint filem it will throw this exception:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component
```

Is there way to make it work?

Comment: Is there a reason why user `abc` doesn't own the job, and so removing the need for `runas`?

Comment: The job has a dependency on MS office. If it runs as user abc directly, I got COM exception. I will add more info to my question

Comment: Is that happening on session 1 as well? Say, did you see the moment of crash by yourself? The exception indicated that DLL initialisation failed which may be related to session 0.

Comment: If I fire up a DOS prompt and run the command there, it is all OK